# CameraX ProcessCameraProvider vs CameraController - which one to use when?

Tags: androidx, android-camerax

Can someone please clarify, when I should use `androidx.camera.view.CameraController` and when `androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider`?
Both seems to be able to start/stop camera using lifecycle events, handle different uses cases (preview, taking pictures, image analysis). Both also work with `androidx.camera.lifecycle.PreviewView`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ProcessCameraProvider` is part of CameraX's lifecycle artifact. It provides access to some/all the device's cameras, allows attaching the lifecycle of the camera (when it opens/closes) to a `lifecycleOwner`, and has a scope of the app's process (it's a Singleton).
In terms of how it's used, it's sort of a low-level API in CameraX, in the sense that when you use it, you'll need to initialize it, create and configure your use cases (i.e `Preview`, `ImageAnalysis`, `ImageCapture`), bind them to a `LifecycleOwner` and then interact with the camera if you'd like to, by getting access to the bound camera's `CameraInfo` and `CameraControl` instances.
And yes, you can use `PreviewView` in this scenario, though you'll have to manually attach it to the `Preview` use case.

`CameraController` is part of CameraX's view artifact, which builds on top of the core APIs CameraX offers to provide a simple API that can easily be plugged into an app and be ready to use. CameraX's view artifact mainly provides `PreviewView` and `CameraController`, the latter handling all the camera setup you'd otherwise need to manually do if you had used APIs like `ProcessCameraProvider`. Besides, `CameraController` handles device rotation (to make sure its use cases receive frames from the camera in the correct orientation), and provides a WYSIWYG experience, ensuring that the output of its use cases match what `PreviewView` displays, and handles touch events (tap-to-focus, pinch-to-zoom) on its attached `PreviewView`. You can check out [this article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/camerax-learn-how-to-use-cameracontroller-e3ed10fffecf) to see what it provides out of the box.

Which API you choose to use depends on your usage needs, `CameraController` provides/handles many of CameraX's core features for you, but is less flexible in terms of use case configuration. So if you need more advanced control over the use cases (e.g setting their resolutions), you'll probably have to set up things manually using `ProcessCameraProvider`.

Comment: Thanks. I indeed used information in mentioned article to implement required feature in my app and it was simple enough. Most of other articles use `ProcessCameraProvider`, with official Google example app to be very completed.